# Using smaller ram to make a larger ram unit?

Tags: design, ram

So far, I figure I need to divide the 2k x 22 RAM's into a 4 parallel connection to get the 3 bits data out, and I assume I'm going to need 3G/2K= 125000 rows of RAM, but I'm not sure out to set up the addressing in for the RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right for the 4 parallel connection. The the amount of rows, I'm not quite sure your calculus is right, though.  1G is 1'024*1'024*1'024, not 1'000'1000, but apart from that, you would use multiplexers.

The first 11 lowest address lines would be pinned directly to all chips' address bus.  Then, you link the data lines of all chip that contain the same data "byte". (i.e. All Data 0 to 7 together, all Data 8 to 15, etc.)  That would result in 32 data lines linked to 128K chips each (assuming 128k is the amount you intended at first).

Finally, the upper address bits (12 up to 31) would be used as the select lines of a super-duper gigantic demultiplexer which would define which "rows of chips"' ChipSelect (typically CS) line would be tied low to enable the chip's output.

Comment: So 1G equals 128K?

Comment: Well, depends if you are talking about 1Gigabit or 1 gigabyte.
1gigabit = 1024*1024*1024 bits, while 1gigabyte = 1024*1024*1024*8 bits.

Also, real memory chips are typically byte, word, double-word, etc. wide.  However you must look carefully in datasheet to verify whether it is 2Kb or 2KB.

Comment: Also your question is somewhat a duplicate of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/94755/construct-an-8k-x-32-rom-using-2k-x-8-rom-chips?rq=1

Comment: Yeah it's bytes, so I would have 21 rows of 4 parallel 8K x 8 chips with each row's CS inputs corresponding to an output from a  5 to 32 decoder right?

Comment: 1024*1024*1024*8 = 1GB
1024*8*8 = 8KB
(1024*1024*1024*8)/(1024*8*8) = 32768 rows of 4 chips

Comment: I don't know what you are actually trying to achieve, but I hope you are doing this as an academic exercice, because it is probably a very bad idea to do that kind of setup.  Even on a PCB, that would take a lot of trace and you would have both crosstalk and latency problems, causing you RAM to be unusable even at quite low frequencies.

Comment: AHHHHHHH thank you I understand now, for some reason I was stuck on the thought that I would need a decoder of some extremely large size.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to learn how to do connections of RAM chips together to make larger RAM chips

Comment: Well, don't do that!  You'd better buy a larger chip.  You will have better latency and most importantly, a much lower cost.  Buying from any supply such as Digikey, Mouser or the like is a much better idea if you expect to pin more than 4 memory chip.  My engineering degree is almost completed, so I have quite some experience with that kind of setup.  And it fails :(